# RedisCache() wont accept Predis/Client() as instance of Redis

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, redis

I've been stuck at this for days. I tried searching for similar issues in the web but no dice :(

I followed this [guide](http://olegpuzanov.com/2015/02/01/using-redis-for-doctrine-caching-in-symfony2/)

its kinda old, and I used the Doctrine\Common\Cache\RedisCache() instead of snc. The problem is that whenever i try to run:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Predis\Client;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\RedisCache;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/Worker", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {

            $predis = new RedisCache();
            $predis->setRedis(new Client());

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        ));
    }
}
```

It gives me an error

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Cache\RedisCache::setRedis() must be an instance of Redis, instance of Predis\Client given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\src\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php on line 22 and defined
```

I'm requiring predis/predis 1.1.1 in my composer.json btw

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.11.3",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "snc/redis-bundle": "2.x-dev",
    "predis/predis": "1.1.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I have to use Doctrine\Common\Cache\PredisCache() with Predis\Client() if I want to use predis. (the method used in the link is outdated)

```
use Predis\Client;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\PredisCache;

$predis = new PredisCache(new Client());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
        $predis->setRedis(new \Redis());
```

instead of:

```
        $predis->setRedis(new Client());
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)